# use of の in this sentence

Tags: particle-の

I still have some trouble with the の　particle sometimes.

I'm doing my Bunpro reviews rn and he translation gives me sth like "the one that..."

I didn't quite understand the exact concept behind this particular case though.

Thanks for reading.

[image: my review on Bunpro]

Comment: Maybe look at a dictionary for the meaning of sentence-final の? That translation is wrong btw.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Are you sure that's a sentence-final の? Given the omission of ですか in the question I was assuming that there was a です omitted in the answer. So it's an AがBです sentence where B is 'the well lit one'.

Comment: If the sentence was 一番明るいのは息子の部屋 then that meaning of の works, but it’s way too awkward to interpret it like that in the provided sentence. Unclear if the translation is wrong or the person who wrote the JP sentence made a mistake in the first place I guess.

Comment: @user3856370 It’s possible that’s what the person who wrote then sentence was going for if they are non-native, but it doesn’t work unfortunately. Only way to interpret it is as sentence-final.

Comment: Yeah, it did seem weird to me but I wasn't sure. I'd bet that was the intention though.

Comment: This の looks fairly unnatural, and the English translation is wrong, too. It's impossible to explain this usage of の because it's used wrongly in the first place...